# FFMPEG Trimming Issue in Docker Container for Safari-recorded Videos

Tags: python, linux, docker, ffmpeg, safari

I am facing an issue with FFMPEG while attempting to trim a video to a specific duration in a Docker container. The trimming works perfectly on my local machine (M1 Pro), but when I run the same code in a Docker container (using the python:3.8-slim-buster image), the generated clip is only 1 second long instead of the intended 5 seconds.

The problem seems to be specific to videos recorded on Safari, as videos recorded on Google Chrome work as expected on both local and container environments.

Here is the code I am using for trimming:

```
def get_clip(source, generated_file_name, till_second=5):
    logging.info("***** Generating Clip *****")
    command = f'ffmpeg -y -i {source} -t {till_second} -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental {generated_file_name}'
    os.system(command)
    logging.info("***** Clip Generated *****")
    return generated_file_name
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /python-docker

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gcc python3-dev -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 -y

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/../../torch.libs/libgomp-6e1a1d1b.so.1.0.0 && python app.py
```

I suspect there might be compatibility issues with ffmpeg versions or codecs between my local machine and the container. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I've tried using different libraries on python i.e Moviepy, but since they use FFMPEG behind the scenes, so no luck. Also I tried to use OpenCV but it doesn't extract the audio. Lastly I also tried to extract audio seperately using PyDub but that also extracted the audio of just one second only